# Complex MySQL search query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below query running on my `users` and `chats` table to join and I'm trying to `group by` on my `chats` table for `user_id OR receiver_id` not just `user_id` like you can see below in SQL query inside `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT c.*, users.username, users.firstname, users.lastname 
FROM chats c 
INNER JOIN( SELECT MAX(created) AS Date, user_id, receiver_id, chat, type, id 
FROM chats 
WHERE receiver_id = 286 OR user_id = 286 
GROUP BY user_id ) cc ON cc.Date = c.created AND cc.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = c.user_id 
WHERE c.receiver_id = 286 OR c.user_id = 286
```

I tried `GROUP BY user_id OR receiver_id` but I can't seem to get information for id 286 for either receiver_id or user_id.

Is there a way we can achieve it and group by so that we can look into both columns and come up with results from both?

Do I need to do two queries and join them together instead?

Comment: Just to be sure, does your `charts` table contain any rows with user_id 286 or receiver_id 286?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for most recent chat record, why don't you just sort the results by created and get the first row like this:

```
SELECT c.*, users.username, users.firstname, users.lastname 
FROM chats c, users u
WHERE (c.receiver_id = 286 OR c.user_id = 286) AND
      u.id = c.user_id 
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm looking for most recent chat record for each unique user_id or receiver_id....